# Добавление WooCommerce product add-ons в корзину

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, корзина

Есть плагин WooCommerce product add-ons, который позволяет дополнительные опции прописывать для товара. Эти опции отображаются на странице товара и там же включаются/выключаются чекбоксом.

Есть ли способ добавить такое же для корзины? Чтобы покупатель прямо из корзины мог добавлять эти опции, и они сохранялись при оформлении заказа. Сталкивался ли кто-то с данной проблемой? Буду рад услышать любые предложения по решению этой проблемы.